# FindViewByID - Null Pointer Exception! [ANDROID STUDIO]

Tags: java, android, findviewbyid

I am very new with Android Studio, so there are many things I Need help for.

One of these is that annoying `findViewById()`.

Here is the most important part of my `MainActivity.java`

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

public Button kreisd;
public Button kugeld;
public Button kreiscalc;

public Context con;

public EditText radius_eingabe;

public TextView kreis_ergebnis_vol;
public TextView kreis_ergebnis_G;

public String str1;

public double st1;
public double G_kreis;
public static final double PI = 3.141592653589793d;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    kreisd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.kreis);
    kugeld = (Button)findViewById(R.id.kugel);
    kreiscalc = (Button)findViewById(R.id.calc_kreis);

    kreisd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            con = MainActivity.this;
            setContentView(R.layout.kreislay);
        }
    });

    kreiscalc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            con = MainActivity.this;

            str1 = radius_eingabe.toString();
            st1 = Double.parseDouble(str1);
            G_kreis = PI*st1*st1;
            kreis_ergebnis_G = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.G_kreis);
            kreis_ergebnis_G.setText("" + G_kreis);



        }
    });


}`
```

It always gives me that error: (again most important part)

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
```

I know, many of you think, that `kreiscalc`,(the button that causes the error) doesn't exist!
But it does. I have two different layouts: One where all the other stuff is and the second one, where `kreiscalc` is. So, does this `findViewById()` - method only find IDs being in the first ( and main) layout? I Need help. Thanks for your attention!

EDIT: Got it know! Simply use the LayoutInflanter! SO:

`final LayoutInflanter lf = getLayoutInflanter();
View view2 = lf.inflate(R.layout.YOURLAYOUTNAME, null);
Button kreiscalc = (Button) view2.findViewById(R.id.calc_kreis);`

Comment: well your kreiscalc is null so there is no id in your calckreis or you just need to rebuild your project or c) it might be that _ makes problem try to remove this

Comment: Edited: Yes, it will search `kreiscalc` in main layout because of this: `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far I understand the button with id `calc_kreis` doesn't exist on the "current" view and that's why `findViewById` returns null.

Method `findViewById` will only return widgets contained by the view you set on `setContentView`. If the button is placed on other view, your code will never work.

Comment: Okay! Thanks so far, but how do I change it, so that it can find IDs in different Views?

Comment: @Niemand: I'm not aware that you have any way to do that. You only can access controls of active views. A potencial solution would be to create a different activity for the other view. It might make more sense.

Answer (score -1):

Yes findViewById only finds views in the active view.

Comment: Dammit jeden UI element ist einen View findViewById.

Miner Deutsche is worse than eiren English.